# How do I enumerate through a JsonElement Array and then convert it to a List?

Tags: c#, json, .net, system.text.json

Note that `JsonElement` is nullable (for a reason elsewhere in my project):

```cs
JsonElement? json = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonElement?>(jsonData);
List<JsonElement?> itemsArray = json?.EnumerateArray().ToList();
```

The error in this code says:

> Cannot convert from List to List<JsonElement?>

Comment: Can you provide the sample value for `jsonData`?

Comment: `jsonData` is just a string of JSON with an array in it. Nothing special/important. It wouldn't cause the compiler any issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with `.Select()` from *System.Linq* to casting each element to `Nullable<JsonElement>` type.

```cs
using System.Linq;

List<JsonElement?> itemsArray = json?.EnumerateArray()
    .Select(x => x as Nullable<JsonElement>)
    .ToList();
```

Or with [`.Cast<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.cast?view=net-7.0).

```cs
List<JsonElement?> itemsArray = json?.EnumerateArray()
    .Cast<JsonElement?>()
    .ToList();
```